# LinkedStack operation methods

Tags: java

I am currently beginning on LinkedStacks and I was wondering why isn't the toString and pop method working? The methods I used are the default given by the book that is Pop and toString methods, the rest I worked for and are functioning well. The push methods add elements perfectly. The peek, looks at the top element without altering the List and Size well returns the count of the times I used the push method. The pop method strangely only works one time then gives out an error. Note on the example that the book gives of the toString method in the section of Stacks doesn't seem function either. I will gladly take any pointers but please know that I am just a beginner and I am learning. This is the code of the class:

## Code

```
public class LinkedStack<T> implements Stack<T> {



private int count;
private LinearNode<T> top;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Creates an empty stack using the default capacity.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public LinkedStack()
{
count = 0;
top = null;
}


    @Override
    public boolean IsEmpty()

    {
        if(top == null)
        {
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        }
        return top == null;
    }

    @Override
    public void Push(T element)
{

    top = new LinearNode(element, top);
    System.out.println(element);
    count++;


}

    @Override 
    public T Pop() 
{
    T result;
    System.out.println("Lets pop the top element!");

    if (count == 0) 
    {
    System.out.println("Pop operation failed. "+ "The stack is empty.");
    }

    result = top.getElement();
    top = top.getNext();
    count--;
    System.out.println("The element that we have poped is :" + result);
    return result;

}

    Override
    public String toString()
{

    String result = "<top of stack>\n";
LinearNode current = top;
while (current != null)
{
result += current.getElement() + "\n";
current = current.getNext();
}
return result + "<bottom of stack>";

}

    @Override
    public T Peek() {
        System.out.println("Lets peek the top element!");
        if(count == 0)
        {
         System.out.println("Peek failed stack is empty");
        }
        System.out.println("The element that we have peeked is: " + top.getElement());
        return top.getElement();

    }

    @Override
    public int Size() {
        System.out.println("The size of the list now is: " + count);
        return count;
    }


    }
```

## Code of main class:

public class LSmain {

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
 LinkedStack<Integer> main = new LinkedStack<>();   
 main.Push(1);
 main.Push(2);
 main.Push(3);
 main.Size();
 main.Peek();
 main.Pop();
 main.Pop();
 main.Size();
 main.toString();


}
```

}

## Output using the pop method twice

```
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
2
3
The size of the list now is: 3
Lets peek the top element!
The element that we have peeked is: 3
Lets pop the top element!
The element that we have poped is: 3
Lets pop the top element!
    at LinkNod.LinkedStack.Pop(LinkedStack.java:64)
    at LinkNod.LSmain.main(LSmain.java:22)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

## Output without using pop method twice

```
run:
1
2
3
The size of the list now is: 3
Lets peek the top element!
The element that we have peeked is: 3
Lets pop the top element!
The element that we have poped is: 3
The size of the list now is: 2
```

## Analysis

/**This actually creates a new Node and stores the value that is inserted in the parameters
Mistake was  that I cannot give top an assignment to the same list, because if I do this the List will be made of only one Node which is the top. Like my past code said, I was only saying that the top brick will equal to itself. So what I understand from the class was to make a new object type LinearNode that stored the elements then top will equal the value of that new Node. Given by this case Pop will work since there will be more Nodes not one. Extra note on the toString method was that simply that the return; in java sometimes displays the value and most of the times it doesnt meaning that you need to add a System.out.println(); in the driver when you call the method or in the method instead.**/

## Push method corrected:

```
@Override
    public void Push(T element)
{

     LinearNode<T> current = new LinearNode<>(element); 

     current.setNext(top);
     top = current;
     count++;


}
```

## Code of main class:

```
public class LSmain {

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
     LinkedStack<Integer> list = new LinkedStack<>();   
     System.out.println("Let's make a List!");
     System.out.println("Push 3 times.");
     System.out.println("Check the size.");
     System.out.println("Peek the top element.");
     System.out.println("Pop three times.");
     System.out.println("The size now should be zero!" + "\n");
     list.Push(1);
     list.Push(2);
     list.Push(3);
     System.out.println(list.toString());
     list.Size();
     list.Peek();
     list.Pop();
     list.Pop();
     list.Pop();
     list.Size();



    }
```

## Functioning output

```
run:
Let's make a List!
Push 3 times.
Check the size.
Peek the top element.
Pop three times.
The size now should be zero!

<top of stack-->[3][2][1]<--bottom of stack>

Let's check the size of the list!
The size of the list is: '3'

Lets peek the top element!
The element that we have peeked is: [3]

Lets pop the top element!
The element that we have poped is: '3'

Lets pop the top element!
The element that we have poped is: '2'

Lets pop the top element!
The element that we have poped is: '1'

The size of the list is...Woah.
The list size is now: '0'
Push more elements!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Thanks for the help! 
PS: I forgot to change the methods declaration to camel case.

## LinearNode code#

/**Had incorrect parameters that gave trouble when I tried to correct the push method by creating a new Node object.**/

package LinkNod;

```
public class LinearNode<T> {

    private LinearNode<T> next; //se guarda la referencia del Nodo
    private T element;          //Lista vacia

    public LinearNode()
{
next = null;
element = null;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Creates a node storing the specified element.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public LinearNode (T elem)
{
next = null;
element = elem;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns the node that follows this one.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public LinearNode<T> getNext()
{
return next;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Sets the node that follows this one.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public void setNext (LinearNode<T> node)
{
next = node;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns the element stored in this node.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public T getElement()//asigna valor
{
return element;
}

public void setElement(T elem)
{

    element = elem;


}



}
```

Comment: can you tell which line is 64?

Comment: in java function names are camel case with a lower case letter first.

Comment: Can you show the code for `LinearNode`? It may be applicable.

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: I forgot to show the LinearNode code and it was incorrect. The parameters had an unnecessary variable there. Next time I'll show the class completely but the LinearNode code is on top. I updated the code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the issue:

```
if (count == 0) 
    {
    System.out.println("Pop operation failed. "+ "The stack is empty.");
    }

    result = top.getElement();  //NPE here perhaps
    top = top.getNext();  
    count--;
    System.out.println("The element that we have poped is :" + result);
    return result;
```

When you trigger the `count == 0` you don't return from the function and instead continue to process the pop operation.

Comment: That does look like an issue, but he pushes 3 times then pops twice. `count` would not be `<=0`.

Comment: Makes sense! Now I notice that the output is Stack is empty. But question what is a NPE?

Comment: @JorgeAVegaVigo NPE == Null Pointer Exception

Comment: You were sir, plus when I pushed I dint actually creat 3 Nodes I was only creating a list of one Node that's why the exception came out when I ran the program. The corrected push method is on top. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- `Pop` doesn't work because you aren't updating the internal references in `LinearNode`
- You also continue to try to pop even when the stack is empty
- You didn't explain why `toString` doesn't work, it looks okay but I would use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and the `.append()` methods.

Comment: What does `"update the internal references in LinearNode"` mean?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers but I did mention that the toString method isn't showing any type of output when I call it.